# Append to variable with "read" command

Tags: bash, variables

With Bash, you can append to a variable, example

```sh
$ foo=Hello

$ foo+=world

$ echo $foo
Helloworld
```

However, is this possible with the `read` command? Something like

```
$ foo=Hello

$ read --append foo
world

$ echo $foo
Helloworld
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fake it, kind of, using `readline`:

```
$ foo=Hello
$ read -e -i"$foo" foo
Hello
```

When using `readline` via the `-e` flag, the argument to `-i` is put on the first line of the input to get you started. You're not so much appending to `foo` as giving `foo` a whole new value, which just happens to begin with the old value if you don't edit the initial line.

Comment: The user asked for bash but I want to note `-i` depends on bash read. It's neither a POSIX feature nor does zsh support it.

Answer (score 7):

Not directly, so use a temp variable.

```
foo="Hello"
read tmp
foo+="$tmp"
```

Comment: Last line should be  foo+=$tmp

Comment: Also (maybe) worth noting, if you don't specify the variable for `read`, the input will be auto-stored in a default variable `$REPLY`; so it could also be: `foo="Hello"; read; foo+=$REPLY;` (though it's no different than this answer =P).